# Why aren't the virtual particles associated with the Lamb Shift real particles?

Tags: field-theory, virtual-particles

In watching the video "The Nature of Nothing" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5rAGfjPSWE) got me wondering why the particles described by Bethe are virtual. It is my understanding (and limited it is) from watching this and trying to research them further, that the virtual particles exist long enough to align themselves along the electric fields shielding the lowest level electrons.  This takes a set time to do even at these small scales.

How long can a virtual particle be "real" before it is no longer considered a virtual particle.  My understanding is that virtual particles return to the vacuum immediately.

Comment: Virtual particles are always virtual. They can be made real (persistent in time) by giving them an amount of energy and momentum. These are unrelated for virtual particled. Some say virtual particles are purely mathematical with no real existence. But their effect is very real. So also thedes vitrual particles.

Comment: can you include a timestamp in the video where Matt talks about Bethe.

Comment: @Vielloosoof You say that their effect is real but for this to be true you need first to impose their existence. If they don't exist and are purely mathematical it does not mean that an effect like Lamb-shift does not exist, just that it has another cause.

Comment: @Jeanbaptiste How can they have an effect if they dont exist?

Comment: @Vielloosoof You have misread my comment.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux Ah. They could be math only. So another cause lays behind the Lamb shift?

Comment: @Vielloosoof what we call virtual particles in QFT are artifacts of the perturbative expansion we use. The Lamb shift is due to the configuration of the quantum fields, which mathematically is asymptotically found by the perturbative expansion. To be short : there is a Lamb shift because there can't be no Lamb-shift, the fields are «shaped» like this because of their interactions and quantum nature.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux But can the atom be described by QFT? And arent the fields changed by interaction? With the vacuum, in which zero field fluctuations (virtual particles) are present?